# Aggregation with rollup and empty records also

Tags: mysql, aggregation

Hello guys I have 3 tables.
Here is the creation data:

```
CREATE TABLE `positionstyp` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bau_nr_komplett` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `positionstyp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `positionstyp` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `projektposition` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `projekt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `preis_vertragskosten` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `positionstyp_id` int(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `positionstyp_id` (`positionstyp_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_projektposition_positionstypID` FOREIGN KEY (`positionstyp_id`) REFERENCES `positionstyp` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `menge` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `baufortschritt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `menge` float NOT NULL,
 `projektposition_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `projektposition_id` (`projektposition_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `menge_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`projektposition_id`) REFERENCES `projektposition` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `positionstyp` (`id`, `parent_id`, `bau_nr_komplett`) VALUES
(1, NULL, '1'),
(2, NULL, '2'),
(3, NULL, '3'),
(4, NULL, '4'),
(5, NULL, '5'),
(6, NULL, '6'),
(7, 3, '325'),
(8, 7, '325.0'),
(9, 7, '325.1'),
(10, 8, '325.0.0');

INSERT INTO `projektposition` (`id`, `projekt_id`, `preis_vertragskosten`, `positionstyp_id`) VALUES
(1, 1325, 100, 3),
(2, 1325, 300, 7),
(3, 1325, 150, 7),
(4, 1325, 200, 10),
(5, 1325, 50, 9);

INSERT INTO `menge` (`id`, `menge`, `baufortschritt`, `projektposition_id`) VALUES
(1, 10, 1, 1),
(2, 20, 20, 2),
(3, 30, 30, 3),
(4, 40, 40, 4),
(5, 50, 100, 5),
(6, 60, 87, 1),
(7, 70, 90, 2),
(8, 80, 10, 3),
(9, 90, 50, 4),
(10, 100, 0, 5),
(11, 1000, 100, 5),
(12, 100, 10, 6);
```

A "menge" is bound to one "projektposition" and a "projektposition" is bound to one "positionstyp". Then a "positionstyp" may have one parent "positionstyp".

In the "menge" there is a field "menge" and a field "baufortschritt" that weightens the "menge". Then the field "preis_vertragskosten" give this combination a price.

So the price for a menge is (`menge`.`menge` * `menge`.`baufortschritt` * `projektposition`.`preis_vertragskosten`)

In my SELECT I want all "positionstyp"-entries with summarized prices and also the "positionstyp"-entries that have no "menge"/"projektposition" under it and so have no price and only for a specific "projekt_id"

My first try was something with group by and rollup but it failed with all "positionstyp" without prices.

Now I have this code that comes near what I want:

```
SELECT 
    pt.id, 
    pt.parent_id, 
    SUM(IF(m.menge IS NULL,0, m.menge * p.preis_vertragskosten * m.baufortschritt/100 * (p.projekt_id=1325))) as summe,
    pt.bau_nr_komplett
FROM positionstyp pt
LEFT JOIN projektposition p     ON (p.positionstyp_id=pt.id) 
LEFT JOIN menge m     ON (m.projektposition_id=p.id) 
GROUP BY pt.id
```

The output summarizes the menge correctly but of course doesn't summarize up the recursive positionstyp_parents. The recursivity of the positionstyp-table can easier be found in the `bau_nr_komplett` field: A positionstyp is a children of all positionstyp, thats bau_nr_komplett are the beginning of the a child-positionstyp`s`bau_nr_komplett` (don't have to be the direct child though).

Does some have an idea?

Thanks and best regards,
Tobias

The result now is:

```
bau_nr_komplett    summe
              1        0     
              2        0     
              3     5230     
              4        0     
              5        0     
              6        0     
            325    22650     
          325.0        0     
          325.1    52500     
        325.0.0    12200
```

The desired result is:

```
bau_nr_komplett   summe
              1   0     
              2   0     
              3   5230+22650+52500+12200     
              4   0     
              5   0     
              6   0     
            325   22650+52500+12200     
          325.0   12200     
          325.1   52500     
        325.0.0   12200
```

-- edit 2:
I found a bad solution. And bad means it works with the test datasets. But with the real database and 100.000s of datasets it need half an hour ;D

```
SELECT pt.bau_nr_komplett, (
 SELECT 
  SUM(IF(m1.menge IS NULL,0,m1.menge*p1.preis_vertragskosten*m1.baufortschritt/100*(p1.projekt_id=1325)))
 FROM positionstyp pt1
 LEFT JOIN projektposition p1 ON ( p1.positionstyp_id = pt1.id ) 
 LEFT JOIN menge m1 ON ( m1.projektposition_id = p1.id ) 
 WHERE pt1.bau_nr_komplett LIKE CONCAT( pt.bau_nr_komplett,  "%" ) 
 ) as summe
FROM positionstyp pt
LEFT JOIN projektposition p ON ( p.positionstyp_id = pt.id ) 
LEFT JOIN menge m ON ( m.projektposition_id = p.id ) 
GROUP BY pt.id
```

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: And how  is positionstyp_id "DEFAULT NULL" !?!?!?!?

Comment: desired result above, in html, sorry. DEFAULT NULL was a copypasteerror

Comment: A copypaste error? Intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself and added some detailed information also:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getProjektsummen`(IN projektID int)
BEGIN
SELECT tttt.id, tttt.parent_id, tttt.bau_nr_komplett, tttt.summe_kostenanschlag, tttt.summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
tttt.summe_vertragskosten, tttt.summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
tttt.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten, tttt.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM (

SELECT id, parent_id,bau_nr_komplett, summe_kostenanschlag, summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
summe_vertragskosten, summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
summe_gemittelteangebotskosten, summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM 
(SELECT tt.id, tt.parent_id, tt.bau_nr_komplett, 
MAX(tt.summe_kostenanschlag) as summe_kostenanschlag,MAX(tt.summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt) as summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
MAX(tt.summe_vertragskosten) as summe_vertragskosten,MAX(tt.summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt) as summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
MAX(tt.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten,MAX(tt.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM (
SELECT ptt.id, ptt.parent_id, coalesce(t.sub9,t.sub8,t.sub7,t.sub6,t.sub5,t.sub4,t.sub3,t.sub2,t.sub1) as bau_nr_komplett, 
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_kostenanschlag,0),0) as summe_kostenanschlag,
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,0),0) as summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt, 
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_vertragskosten,0),0) as summe_vertragskosten, 
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,0),0) as summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt, 
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten,0),0) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten, 
    ROUND(IFNULL(t.summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt,0),0) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    sum(menge * preis_kostenanschlag *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_kostenanschlag,
    sum(menge * preis_kostenanschlag * baufortschritt/100 *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
    sum(menge * preis_vertragskosten *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_vertragskosten,
    sum(menge * preis_vertragskosten * baufortschritt/100 *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
    sum(menge * preis_gemittelte_angebotskosten *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten,
    sum(menge * preis_gemittelte_angebotskosten * baufortschritt/100 *(p.projekt_id=projektID)) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,1) as sub1,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,2) as sub2,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,3) as sub3,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,4) as sub4,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,5) as sub5,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,6) as sub6,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,7) as sub7,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,8) as sub8,
    SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,9) as sub9   
FROM menge m 
    join projektposition p ON (m.projektposition_id=p.id) 
    join positionstyp pt ON (p.positionstyp_id=pt.id)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,1), 
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,2),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,3),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,4),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,5),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,6),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,7),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,8),
SUBSTRING(pt.bau_nr_komplett,1,9)
WITH ROLLUP
) t join positionstyp ptt on (coalesce(t.sub9,t.sub8,t.sub7,t.sub6,t.sub5,t.sub4,t.sub3,t.sub2,t.sub1) = ptt.bau_nr_komplett)
WHERE 
LENGTH(coalesce(t.sub9,t.sub8,t.sub7,t.sub6,t.sub5,t.sub4,t.sub3,t.sub2,t.sub1))<>2 AND
SUBSTRING(reverse(coalesce(t.sub9,t.sub8,t.sub7,t.sub6,t.sub5,t.sub4,t.sub3,t.sub2,t.sub1)),1,1) <> '.' AND
(
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub8) AND LENGTH(t.sub8)=8) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub7) AND LENGTH(t.sub7)=7) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub6) AND LENGTH(t.sub6)=6) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND ISNULL(t.sub6) AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub5) AND LENGTH(t.sub5)=5) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND ISNULL(t.sub6) AND ISNULL(t.sub5) AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub4) AND LENGTH(t.sub4)=4) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND ISNULL(t.sub6) AND ISNULL(t.sub5) AND ISNULL(t.sub4)AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub3) AND LENGTH(t.sub3)=3) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND ISNULL(t.sub6) AND ISNULL(t.sub5) AND ISNULL(t.sub4) AND ISNULL(t.sub3)AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub2) AND LENGTH(t.sub2)=2) OR
(ISNULL(t.sub9) AND ISNULL(t.sub8) AND ISNULL(t.sub7) AND ISNULL(t.sub6) AND ISNULL(t.sub5) AND ISNULL(t.sub4) AND ISNULL(t.sub3) AND ISNULL(t.sub2)AND NOT ISNULL(t.sub1) AND LENGTH(t.sub1)=1))
UNION
SELECT pptt.id as id, pptt.parent_id as parent_id, pptt.bau_nr_komplett as bau_nr_komplett, 
0 as summe_kostenanschlag,
0 as summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
0 as summe_vertragskosten,
0 as summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
0 as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten,
0 as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM positionstyp pptt 
) tt
GROUP BY tt.id) ttt
UNION 
SELECT p1.id, null, concat(pt1.bau_nr_komplett," #"), 
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_kostenanschlag),0),0) as summe_kostenanschlag,
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_kostenanschlag * m1.baufortschritt/100 ),0),0) as summe_kostenanschlag_baufortschritt,
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_vertragskosten ),0),0) as summe_vertragskosten,
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_vertragskosten * m1.baufortschritt/100 ),0),0) as summe_vertragskosten_baufortschritt,
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_gemittelte_angebotskosten ),0),0) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten,
    IFNULL(ROUND(sum(m1.menge * p1.preis_gemittelte_angebotskosten * m1.baufortschritt/100 ),0),0) as summe_gemittelteangebotskosten_baufortschritt
FROM menge m1 JOIN projektposition p1 ON (m1.projektposition_id=p1.id) JOIN positionstyp pt1 ON (p1.positionstyp_id=pt1.id)
WHERE p1.projekt_id=projektID AND p1.positionstyp_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p1.id
) tttt
ORDER BY tttt.bau_nr_komplett;
END
```

And I'm very happy that it works with over 1 Million datasets in menge and 10000 in projektposition and 500 in positionstyp
in 2.5 seconds ^^ !!!